# proper use of 'ip' command to turn on internet access in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, internet

I am new to kali linux.

my downloaded version of kali-linux (download filename : kali-linux-light-2018-4-i386-iso), ip command has replaced ifconfig command, hence I can't use ifconfig command.

when I type 'ifconfig' or '/sbin/ifconfig' at the command window it returns command not found.

The reason to use ifconfig command is that google search results suggested me to use "ifcofig wlan0 up" to get the wireless connection UP.

nmtui command has shown that the needed wifi wireless connection as active.

However, the Firefox browser in kali-linux still can't get access to the internet.

May I know how to use 'ip' command to execute the same purpose of 'ifconfig wlan0 up' or there is some other issues that I didn't set properly to use the internet?

Thanks

Comment: Simply because your question is about Kali does not make it about information security. I'd recommend reading through [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626).

Answer (score 0):

Look into commands like `ip link set wlan0 up`, assuming the Wireless configuration is done.

Kali isn't meant for general purpose computing, so I'd recommend trying another distro until you're used to Linux in general, then move to Debian or Ubuntu, as Kali is very similar to those in command areas.

Comment: thanks for the solution, I tried, and firefox still won't access internet, "ip link show" indicates that wlan0 <Broadcast, multicast, up, lower-up>, so i guess it has nothing to do with getting wlan0 up, as wlan0 is already up

Comment: Hence, the second part of the first sentence :)